# How to convert multi-row JSON file to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm using an instagram scraper that outputs a multi-row JSON file and I'd like to select certain values from that file and assign them to a DataFrame.

When I try to use panda's pd.read_json it only saves the first level to each dataframe.

As an example, I'd like to have a dataframe with the first row that contains (JSON variable in parenthesis):

- Likes ("edge_media_preview_like": {"count": 1356...)
- Comment Count ("edge_media_to_comment": {"count": 44)

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "GraphImages": [
        {
            "__typename": "GraphImage",
            "comments_disabled": false,
            "dimensions": {
                "height": 770,
                "width": 1080
            },
            "display_url": "https:abc123.com",
            "edge_media_preview_like": {
                "count": 1356
            },
            "edge_media_to_caption": {
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "node": {
                            "text": "TEXT EXAMPLE 123"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "edge_media_to_comment": {
                "count": 44
            },
            "gating_info": null,
            "id": "2219687023504340370",
            "is_video": false,
            "media_preview": "abc123media",
            "owner": {
                "id": "212343915"
            },
            "shortcode": "B7N6ZZkhTWS",
            "tags": [],
            "taken_at_timestamp": 1578827334,
            "thumbnail_resources": [
                {
                    "config_height": 150,
                    "config_width": 150,
                    "src": "abc123.com"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 240,
                    "config_width": 240,
                    "src": "abc123.com"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 320,
                    "config_width": 320,
                    "src": "https://abc123.com"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 480,
                    "config_width": 480,
                    "src": "https:/abc123.com"
                },
                {
                    "config_height": 640,
                    "config_width": 640,
                    "src": "https://abc123.com"
                }
            ],
            "thumbnail_src": "https://abc123.com",
            "urls": [
                "https://abc123.com"
            ],
            "username": "abc123"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm looking for:

```
    ImageNumber Likes   CommentCount
0   1           1356    44
1   ...         ...     ...
```

Thank you!

Adding wrong result when using pd.read_json:

```
    GraphImages
0   {'__typename': 'GraphImage', 'comments_disable...
1   {'__typename': 'GraphImage', 'comments_disable...
2   {'__typename': 'GraphImage', 'comments_disable...
3   {'__typename': 'GraphImage', 'comments_disable...
```

Comment: `.read_json()` is nice if it works, but have you tried doing it “manually”?

Comment: @AMC thanks for the quick answer, but I'm not sure how to do it manually on a JSON with so many variables

Comment: You gave an example of the first row, is that all the data you need?

Comment: @AMC by manually you mean the instagram part of collecting data? not sure I'm following

Comment: _by manually you mean the instagram part of collecting data?_ Oh no, I just meant manually as opposed to having `.read_json()` handle everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Turns out that this instagram-scraper outputs a JSON file that is composed of a dictionary, within a list, within a dictionary. The code to extract is as follows:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('ig.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

data['Likes'] = data['GraphImages'][0]['edge_media_preview_like']['count']
...
```

I hope that can help people in the future!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work,

```
import json
with open('ig.json') as json_file:
    dct = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dct, record_path="GraphImages")[["edge_media_preview_like.count", "edge_media_to_comment.count"]].rename({"edge_media_preview_like.count":"Likes", "edge_media_to_comment.count": "CommentCount"}, axis=1)
df["ImageNumber"] = df.index + 1
```

Which produces,

```
    Likes   CommentCount    ImageNumber
0   1356    44              1
```

I'm not sure where the `ImageNumber` is coming from. But I assume it's the order of items appear in `GraphImages`. If so, `df.Index + 1` would give you that.

Comment: Hi @thushv89, thanks for the reply, I'm getting the following error:

"TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Also the name of the file is ig.json if that makes any difference!

Comment: @Gorlomi, did you load your json as a dictionary? I have edited my answer to reflect the full solution.